# Smooth solution for using docker with chef

Tags: docker, chef-infra, google-compute-engine

Scenario: we build docker images with bamboo and push those images up to gcr.io.

chef-client runs will always do a gcloud docker pull to pull down the latest image.  chef-client will not, however, restart the service which would enable the new image.  We restart the service by hand in dev and prod because we don't want chef to kick the service until we're sure the new image works.

So, if we had confidence in our new builds ( which is something we're working on ) is there an elegant way of telling chef-client that a new image has come down, and it needs to restart the service?

It would almost like a "notifies" thing, almost like:

```
custom_docker_image_thingie "docker_image_name" do
  tag node.environment
  notifies :restart, "service[service_name]"
end
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that is how it would look. You would need your `custom_docker_image_thingie` resource to correctly set its `updated?` flag for that to work though. There are some helpers for doing that you building a resource out of other, smaller resources (12.5 custom resources syntax, `use_inline_resources`, `notifying_block`) but for something built entirely from scratch you need to write that code yourself.